# handling tcl expect application crash

Tags: bash, unix, tcl, expect

Is it possible to spawn an application, send commands, expect results, but also 'respawn' the application in case it crashed and continue from the last point? I tried creating procedures for spawning, but I am not able to catch user shell prompt once the application gets closed

Comment: The first idea that comes to mind is to make a list of commands that are likely to crash and run them in a child process from the main expect script.

Comment: application crashed just like that

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to get a shell prompt after the crash. I would expect you to get the return code from the crash (and possibly the sigsegv/etc. output messages though). Can you use those? That being said you can't "restart" where you left off unless the application can handle that somehow.

Comment: @meso_2600: if the application crashed in a child process, *at least* you may have a chance to read a non-zero exit code and try rerunning it.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca thats the problem, how do I read that code :) I have to pass commands to the application, in case it crashes I have to run it again and start from the last command I used.

Comment: @meso_2600: Well, if someone just called `kill -9 <application PID>`, then I have no solution for this problem!

Comment: @EugeniuRosca I really shouldn't care who or what killed or crashe dthe program. I have tasks to do, application crashes, I restart the application and CONTINUE the process, not restart it. If I could restart whole process that would be easier, but some commands are not allowed to be run twice

Comment: Ugh, this sort of question attracts a “that depends”. It's critically dependent on exactly what you're doing, and on what “crashed” means for you (I've seen exiting with an error described as a crash, despite that not actually being so). More details required…

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you are doing something like telneting or sshing
into a shell then running an application. The application dies or
hangs so the prompt does not return so expect does not return and so
you are stuck.   You will need to use timeout  to detect a hang  and restart
your entire process ( including the spawn). Below is the boiler plate I start with when writing
expect scripts.  The critical thing to help you resolve your problem
is to realize that spawn not only sets the spawn_id but also returns
the pid of the spawned process. You can use that pid to kill the
spawned process if you get an eof and/or a timeout. My boiler plate
kills the spawn process on timeout. The timeout does not bail from the
expect loop but waits for the eof before exiting. it also accumulates
the output of expect command so on timeout you may be able to see
where it dies. The boilerplate is in a proc called run.  Spawn the process
and pass the pid and the spawn id . Reuse the boiler plate to define other
procs that will be the steps. put the procs in a script with a counter between
them as shown and repeat. The other answerer is correct that the unless the app
restarts where you left off you  can need to start from scratch. If it does start from
where you left off. make the steps granular enough that you know what command
to repeat. and step to start from. 
BoilerPlate

```
proc run { pid spawn_id buf } {
    upvar $buf buffer;  #buffer to accumulate output of expect
    set bad 0;
    set done 0;
    exp_internal 0; # set to one for extensive debug
    log_user 0; # set to one to watch action
    expect {
        -i $spawn_id
        -re {} {
                append buffer $expect_out(buffer); # accumultate expect output
                exp_continue;
        }
        timeout { 
               send_user "timeout\n"
               append buffer $expect_out(buffer); # accumultate expect output
               exec kill -9 $pid
               set bad 1
               exp_continue;
            }
        fullbuffer {
              send_user " buffer is full\n"
              append buffer $expect_out(buffer); # accumultate expect output
               exp_continue;
            }
        eof { 
                 send_user "Eof detected\n"
                 append buffer $expect_out(buffer); # accumultate expect output
                 set done 1 ;
            }
    }
    set exitstatus [ exp_wait -i $spawn_id ];
    catch { exp_close -i $spawn_id };
    if { $bad } {
        if { $done } {
            throw EXP_TIMEOUT  "Application timeout"
        } 
        throw BAD_ERROR  "unexpected failure "
    }   
    return $exitstatus
}


set count 0
set attempts 0 ; # try 4 times
while { $count == 0  && $attempts < 4 } {
    set buff ""
    set pid [spawn -noecho  ssh user@host ]
    try {
        run $pid $::spawn_id buff
        incr count
        run2 $pid $::spawn_id buff
        incr count
        run3 $pid $::spawn_id buff
        incr count
        run4 $pid $::spawn_id buff
        incr count
    } trap EXP_TIMEOUT { a b } {
        puts "$a $b"
        puts " program failed at step $count"
    } on error { a b } { 
        puts "$a $b"
        puts " program failed at step $count"
    } finally {
        if { $count == 4 } {
            puts "success"
        } else { 
            set count 0
            incr attempts
            puts "$buff" 
            puts "restarting\n"
        } 
    }
}
```